# Github managing branches of team

Tags: git, github, merge

So I'm working with another guy in github and we both have our own branch call tim and scott. All branches have the same code, but Scott just edited something in the code. He commited and pushed to his branch. He then merged with master which worked. Now when scott goes back to his branch He edits again. I edit also. Do I just merge to master, then scott merges with master? We kept having problems with keeping the project right. How do I make the project so we can just update based on what we have, even if we're working on it at the same time?

**REPHRASED**: I have code slightl different from my friend's and want to merge them together into the master. how would i do this?

Comment: It is tricky to know exactly what you are asking.  What is your desired behavior?  What does "can just update based on what we have" mean exactly?

Comment: @BlackVegetable I'm trying to have me and my friends code put in master, but mix in together.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a complete branching model, not private branches which are not in sync together. http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/